# What's the use of union types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

First off, there are no official guidelines (AFAIK as of March 8, 2015) on using this new feature of TypeScript called the union types. Well, I tried to find a way of using them myself.  It hasn't been easy. I am still struggling to find a place for union types in my code:

- they can't be used with interfaces since there is no reliable runtime check that would tell whether a value implements an interface
- they can't be used with generics due to issues with the type inference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2264

What is left?

- mixing primitives (destructuring via typeof)
- mixing classes (destructuring via instanceof)

Am I right that those 2 are the only valid ways of consuming union types in TypeScript  at the moment?

If so, are there any plans to extend their applicability?

If no, what am I missing out?

Comment: Not an answer, just to point out that in d.ts files they are pretty awesome as either you used to be stuck with "any". For example, if a property type was a string or a HTMLDivElement.  Plus you would need a ton of Overload soup depending on the library. This has all been cleaned up with union types.  Your question is great though because I never considered non-d.ts file usage and cannot see why they would be used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get a single answer for this; at the very least, union types handle many different use cases that enable users to write TypeScript in a manner similar to how they might write canonical JavaScript. Here's an attempt to explain anyway.

When you have two types that are structurally (and ideally functionally) similar, one benefit is that you can use the intersection of properties that they share as a point of abstraction.

In the cases where you have two types that are not structurally similar, but have parallels in how they their information can be treated, it can be useful for making a function for normalizing that information into a common abstracted form.

As an example, ES6 tagged templates are very similar to call expressions:

```
f `hello ${ 123 } ${ 456 } world!`
```

The above tagged template desugars to something similar to the following:

```
var _t = ["hello ", " ", " world!"];
_t.raw = ["hello ", " ", " world!"];
f(_t, 123, 456);
```

You could imagine that in a compiler, it would be ideal if they could be treated equally to call expressions when convenient, but handled specially when the two are distinct enough. Let's try to model this:

```
interface TemplateExpression extends Expression {
    // ...
}

interface TaggedTemplateExpression extends Expression{
    callTarget: Expression;
    template: TemplateExpression;
}

interface CallExpression extends Expression {
    callTarget: Expression;
    arguments: Expression[];
}

type CallLikeExpression = CallExpression | TaggedTemplateExpression;

function getEffectiveCallArguments(expr: CallLikeExpression): Expression[] {
    if (expr.kind === SyntaxKind.CallExpression {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }

    // OR, if you don't want to have a tag,
    // you could check expr's properties
    if ((<CallExpression>expr).arguments) {
        // treat as CallExpression
    }
    else {
        // treat as TaggedTemplateExpression
    }
}
```

Both `CallExpression` and `TaggedTemplateExpression` have a `callTarget` in common, so you can always get the expression being invoked from a `CallLikeExpression` by just using the `callTarget` property.

If you'd like to get the arguments that will be fed into call, you can extract it using `getEffectiveCallArguments` which is aware of how do deal with the differences between the two.